# Font sticking out of Its container

Tags: css, font-face, containers

I am dipping my toe into font-face and have used font-squirrel to create the necessary files for a cursive font called tangerine.

I want to use it for pull quotes so have created a small floated area over to the right. I notice that the top of the letters go out beyond the edge of the container. The text is written thus:

```
<p><span class="quote">I would recommend the sessions to all mums.</span>Mel very quickly gauged the kind of person ...</p>
```

Here's the css:

```
.quote {
width:250px;
float:right;
margin:0 0 20px 20px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 15px;
border-left:4px solid #F61942;
border-left:4px solid #FBC7D0;
background:#b7e6fa;
font-family:tangerine-regular;
font-size:54px; 
color:#A675CD;
line-height:1;  
}
```

Why is the quote sticking out of its box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

1. Your text is too big is half-ing the text.
2. Your width isn't bigger enough.

Without changing one of these you'll not be able to Achive what you're trying to, as I've explained before if you add this slice of code and change your font or the width you'll be able to achive it.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

This causes the text to stay into the div - [Here to see the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swqzq/)

Comment: thanks - but it cuts words in half... so cant really do that.

Comment: It's because 1) Your font is too big 2) your width isn't bigger enough. It won't work unless you change of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that writing this: font-family:tangerine-regular; You display this font only on computers that actually have it installed?

I would increase padding on the right.. word-wrap: break-word is good idea but not in this case..

```
.quote {
width:235px;
padding:5px 20px 5px 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swqzq/1/

Comment: It should work for everyone. I've gave this answer to someone before and had no problems.

Comment: thanks -  in the css I do have the links to the tangerine files so I think it should be embedding the font ok? I would have thought that the browser would calculate where to put the letters/words such that it fits within the container = like it does for other fonts... don't see why its nots working here